# If E is a measurable set , can we prove that there exist an open set F which satisfy that $m(F) \geq m(E)-\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis

If E is measurable, we can prove that there exist an open set F which satisfy that for every $\epsilon \geq 0$, $ m_*(E-F) \leq \epsilon$ ($m_*$ is the outer measure), but how can I prove that $ m(E)-m(F) \leq \epsilon$  (m is Lebesgue measure)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider that for the open set $F$ with $$m_*(E-F) \leq \epsilon$$ it has to hold $F \subseteq E$ but if $E$ is measurable and $F$ is open (hence measurable) then $E-F$ is also measurable hence $m_*(E-F) = m_(E-F)$ and so from $$m_*(E-F) \leq \epsilon$$ it follows $$m(E-F) \leq \epsilon$$ but $m(E-F) = m(E) - m(F)$ by properties of the Lebesgue  measure.

Comment: thanks, I get your point.